# Objectify - App Engine Storing a List

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I want to have `List<P>` in my entity `P`:

```
@Entity
@Index
public class P {
    @Id Long id;
    String email;
    List<P> list = new ArrayList<P>();
}
```

But every time I insert new entity I can see `email` and `id` in datastore viewer, but no `list`:/ Is any special work with lists?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Please give some more details. What you are presenting here cannot be done.

Comment: Want to have list of friends, buddies or something like this. Literally I want to have list of objects inside object the same type. If I want to have friend list, friend in fact will extends P or it will contain P. What is the best approach to have that kind of list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proposal would be to store each entity `P` separately and just keep a reference to the other `P` entities it "includes". So, you could have somthing like the following:

```
@Entity
@Index
public class P {
    @Id Long id;
    String email;
    List<Key<P>> list = new ArrayList<Key<P>>();
}
```

This way, you can still have access to all of your "children" entities, but without having all the information inside the main `P` entity.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you.  I was getting `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when I called `ObjectifyService.register()`. I had circular dependencies like in the original problem. I resolved this by converting the field from type `List<P>` to `List<Ref<P>>` (similar to your solution of `List<Key<P>>` I think).

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a list of P in your P entity for objectify.  There cannot be any circular dependencies.

You also need to use the @Embed keyword for embedding entities inside entities.  Look here: http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Embedded_Collections_and_Arrays

Answer (score 0):

More detailed answer:

```
package com.netcomps.objectify_test;

import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Parent;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;

import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
public class User {
  @Parent Key<World> theWorld;
  @Id public Long id;

  public String email;
  public String name;
  @Index public Date date;
  //public ArrayList<User> friends;
  List<Key<User>> friends;

  /**
   * Simple constructor just sets the date
   **/
  public User() {
    date = new Date();
  }

  /**
   * A connivence constructor
   **/
  public User(String world, String name) {
    this();
    if( world != null ) {
        theWorld = Key.create(World.class, world);  // Creating the Ancestor key
    } else {
        theWorld = Key.create(World.class, "default");
    }
    this.name = name;
  }

  /**
   * Takes all important fields
   **/
  public User(String book, String content, String email) {
    this(book, content);
    this.email = email;
  }


  public void addFriend(User friend) {
      if (friends == null) {
          friends = new ArrayList<Key<User>>();
      }
      Key<User> f = Key.create(theWorld, User.class, friend.id);
      friends.add(f);
  }


}
```